Android custom permission problem on Google store releases
I have 2 apps. App 1 is a provider, allowing app 2 to read a database. To make sure both apps will work fine despite of the order of installation, I declared 2 custom permissions in app 1 with "signature" protection level and released the both apps using the same key store and key alias.
In app 1 manifest:
<permission
      android:name="${MyApp1}.permission.WRITE_DATABASE"
      android:label="Write Database"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<permission
      android:name="${MyApp1}.permission.READ_DATABASE"
      android:label="Read Database"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application>
...
    <provider
        android:authorities="${MyApp1}.content.provider.MyProvider"
        android:name=".content.provider.MyProvider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="${MyApp1}.permission.WRITE_DATABASE"
        android:writePermission="${MyApp1}.permission.READ_DATABASE"
     />
</application>

In app 2 manifest, I used those tow permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="${MyApp1}.permission.WRITE_DATABASE" />
<uses-permission android:name="${MyApp1}.permission.READ_DATABASE" />

They worked as expected on my local machine. However, when I test those two app downloaded from Google store, app 2 now can not read the database from app 1 anymore. I got an error on app 2 with the message: Permission Denial: opening provider ... requires com.MyApp1.permission.WRITE_DATABASE or com.MyApp1.permission.READ_DATABASE
I double checked the Setup/App signing tab on the Google Play Console. The two apps have the same fingerprints in the Upload key certificate section, but those in App signing key certificate section are different.
Dose anyone know what could possibly happen? Is it because of the difference in App signing key certificate between the two apps?
Thank you in advance!

I think so, ultimately app signing certificate is what is used to sign the apps. End user devices are not even aware of upload key existence so them being equal doesn't matter. For this case you might need to opt out from play console key management and manually upload same app keys.

@Pawel I applied the signing key from app 2 to app 1 on Google play console, but nothing changed. Looks like there is something else.
